# Nokogiri implementation assistance

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/panel_holder" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/notification_panel" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/notification_container_parent" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" bounds="[0,0][768,120]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="true" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/header" text="" index="1">
<node class="android.widget.LinearLayout" bounds="[48,8][153,62]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/clock" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.TextView" bounds="[48,21][103,59]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/time_view" text="5:28" index="0"/>
<node class="android.widget.TextView" bounds="[103,21][153,59]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/am_pm_view" text=" PM" index="1"/>
</node>
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[16,62][260,100]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/date_group" text="" index="1">
<node class="android.widget.TextView" bounds="[48,62][260,100]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/date_expanded" text="Monday, March 6" index="0"/>
</node>
<node class="android.widget.LinearLayout" bounds="[542,0][658,120]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/system_icons_super_container" text="" index="3">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[542,35][650,85]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/system_icons_container" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.LinearLayout" bounds="[542,35][650,85]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/system_icons" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.LinearLayout" bounds="[547,43][631,77]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/signal_cluster" text="" index="1">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[547,43][583,77]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="Wifi signal full." package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/wifi_combo" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.ImageView" bounds="[547,43][583,77]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/wifi_signal" text="" index="0"/>
</node>
<node class="android.widget.LinearLayout" bounds="[583,43][617,77]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/mobile_signal_group" text="" index="1">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[583,43][617,77]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="3G Phone two bars." package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/mobile_combo" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.ImageView" bounds="[583,43][617,77]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/mobile_signal" text="" index="0"/>
</node>
</node>
</node>
<node class="android.view.View" bounds="[631,45][650,74]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="Battery 100 percent." package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/battery" text="" index="2"/>
</node>
</node>
</node>
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[658,0][726,120]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/multi_user_switch" text="" index="4">
<node class="android.widget.ImageView" bounds="[670,38][714,82]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/multi_user_avatar" text="" index="0"/>
</node>
</node>
</node>
</node>
<node class="android.view.View" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/scrim_behind" text="" index="1"/>
<node class="android.view.View" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/scrim_in_front" text="" index="2"/>
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[0,0][768,50]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/status_bar" text="" index="3">
<node class="android.widget.LinearLayout" bounds="[0,0][768,50]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/status_bar_contents" text="" index="0">
<node class="android.widget.FrameLayout" bounds="[12,0][575,50]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="false" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="false" enabled="true" clickable="false" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="" package="com.android.systemui" resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/notification_icon_area" text="" index="0"/>
</node>
</node>
</node>
</hierarchy>
```

I have an XML file  and am trying to extract the "text" attribute, "ana.zx" for example, and either place it in a different file, or just convert it into strings.

I managed to get to the point where I saved the file onto storage and open it, but I haven't figured out how to use Nokogiri to extract that attribute.

This is what I have so far:

```
doc = File.open("window_dump.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f)}
```

Comment: Your XML is **not well-formed**. Please edit your code-sample and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" _including the linked pages_ and "[mcve]" along with “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Your question shows no attempt to find a node. You need to read the Nokogiri tutorials and cheat sheet, search here on SO and on the internet, try things, and then ask a detailed, specific question about a specific problem. Also, reduce your sample XML to the bare minimum, smallest chunk, that will duplicate the problem. Anything beyond that wastes our time trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is invalid. The XML specification is very strict, so documents must be valid, unlike HTML which is puppy-dog friendly.

Here are the errors Nokogiri found:

```
 # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document>,
 #     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: node line 4 and hierarchy>,
 #     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag hierarchy line 3>]
```

After parsing a document use the `errors` method on the returned value to see what Nokogiri had to do to parse the document. If there are errors, it's likely that Nokogiri had to alter the document just to return something, and those altered nodes can hide information. In your document's case it's very early in the text so you could lose access to all subsequent children nodes.

If `errors` shows a problem exists then use an XML validator if you need more information. At a minimum I'll pull the file into Vim and let it reformat the document so I can check its indentation/nesting as usually the problem is due to a missing closing tag.

Also, here's how we typically open and parse a file using Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('path/to/file.xml'))
```

Nokogiri will read and close the file for you so using a block is unnecessary.

Comment: This XML file is a result of "adb shell uiautomator dump" syntax that shows all visible elements on Android device. I have to work with it ...

Comment: Then you'll have to do fixups prior to parsing. A parser expects valid XML.